# Java regex for finding combo of { and number

Tags: java, regex

I have a file with following information

> Hi my {4 name is {4: Jeremy I {4: work in {4 Texas My job is {3 very
>   {0 hard, I work until 4

I need to match all {4 values in this text, so I tried to write following regex: `[\{4^:]`

But when I try this on a regex tester, it matches all occurances of **{**, **4** and **:** but I only want the combination of {4 without a : in it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All 4 occurrences? If you need to match `{4` not followed with `:`, use `String res = s.replaceAll("\\{4(?!:)", "newValue");`. If you need to replace all `{4`, just use `.replace("{4", "NEW_VALUE")` - no need for a regex.

Comment: what do you mean  ***...to match all {4***, you dont need regex for that...

Comment: Don't use `[...]` (character class)

Comment: You need to `.replace("{4:", "<NEWVAL>:")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative lookahead to remove `{4` which are followed by `:`. Also remove square brackets as they will match all of the results individually.

```
{4(?!:)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/IiM826/3)

1. `{4` matches the characters `{4` literally
2. `(?!:)` is negative lookahead which means look for `{4` which are not followed by `:`